# Voronoi object for CNC mill

Tags: obj, custom-attributes

I have been using Blender for some time now but I am unable to solve this problem that I have. I need an object with Voronoi textures similar to the picture attached but I need to be able to change it (depth, size of objects etc.) as I will have multiple designs. I have tried procedural texture but the problem is I cannot extract this to .obj or other 3D format which I need to import to Fusion 360 for manufacture.

Does anybody know a way that I can create this and be able to adjust and modify it so that I have different outcomes?

Thank you

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Here's a GN group which takes a shot at a parametric version of your tile:

[image]

It exposes box-size in XYZ,mesh resolution, Voronoi scale and offset, and cell-depth, to the modifier interface. You'd have to go into the group and tweak the *Float Curve*, though, to adjust the smoothness of the cupping. If you wanted to expose that to the interface, too, a bit more maths would be needed, and a decision on how you'd like to control it.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like the job for a displacement modifier with a Voronoi texture.

Extrude a plane the desired thickness and add only the top vertex to a vertex group.

Subdivide the plane sufficiently for the desired level of detail with a *Subdivision Surface* modifier set to *Simple* and a high *Subdivision* value.

Add a displace modifier with a *Voronoi* texture, from the *Texture* tab of the properties window.

Set it to influence only the vertex group you previously created so it doesn't deform the bottom part.

[image]